# ¿Cómo poner cada elemento de una lista en una columna diferente de un dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tengo una dataframe con una columna que contiene una tabla y me gustaria poner cada de sus elementos en una columna differente. Por ejemplo con la dataframe siguiente:

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,Unnamed: 0.1.1,URL,QID,Questions,Answers,QType
0,0,0,1,When do you think your next vacation can start?,"['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']",
1,1,1,2,What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?,"[""Doctor's availability in hotel"", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']",
2,2,2,3,What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?,"['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']",
3,3,3,4,,What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?,"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']",
4,4,4,5,Consumer Personality,[],
```

Me gustaria:

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,Unnamed: 0.1.1,URL,QID,Questions,Answers,Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4,Answer5, Answer6, Answer7, Answer8,Answer9, Answer10
0,0,0,1,When do you think your next vacation can start?,"['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']",'In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed'
1,1,1,2,What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?,"[""Doctor's availability in hotel"", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']",""Doctor's availability in hotel"", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care', 
2,2,2,3,What is your preferences of complementary breakfast?,"['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']",'Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only'
3,3,3,4,,What is your preference for a in-hotel grocery shops for the basic necessity items and packaged food?,"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']",
4,4,4,5,Consumer Personality,[],'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
```

Intenté:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    l = row['Answers']
    l = ast.literal_eval(l)
    j = 0
    for answer in l:
        try:
            print("answer: ", answer)
            df['Answer' + str(j) ] = answer
        except ValueError:
            print("ValueError with: ", ValueError)
        j+=1
```

Pero sólo mantiene los valores en la última columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He creado un conjunto de datos para simular un subconjunto de tu ejemplo así:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['www1', 'www2', 'www3'], 'QID': [1, 2, 3],'Questions':['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],'QType':['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'],'Answers':[[['Q1A1','Q1A2','Q1A3']], [['Q2A1','Q2A2']], [['Q3A1','Q3A2','Q3A3','Q3A4']]]})
print(df)
```

El **`df`** inicial se ve así:
[image: dataframe inicial]

A continuación, puedes crear un nuevo un dataframe convirtiendo las respuestas en columnas ([aquí otro ejemplo](https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/python/como-convertir-una-columna-con-una-lista-de-valores-en-filas-en-pandas-dataframe/828201472/)):

```
df2=(df['Answers'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
     .join(df['QID'], how='left')
)
print (df2)
```

Hecho esto, **`df2`** tiene esta pinta:

[image: dataframe 2]

Y finalmente, haciendo un join entre **`df`** y **`df2`** por el **ID** de la pregunta (**`QID`**):

```
result= pd.merge(df.iloc[:, 0:3], df2, left_on='QID', right_on='QID')
print (result)
```

Esto te dará como resultado tu dataframe inicial con una columna adicional por cada respuesta:

[image: resultado final]

Espero haber interpretado correctamente tu conjunto inicial de datos y que esto sea aplicable a tu caso.

---

**Edición:**

Añado otra opción de resolverlo, ajustando la lista de la columna Answers (ya que en la solución 1 he puesto doble corchete en la lista **`[[]]`**):

```
import pandas as pd

df3=pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['www1', 'www2', 'www3'], 'QID': [1, 2, 3],'Questions':['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'],'QType':['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3'],'Answers':[['Q1A1','Q1A2','Q1A3'], ['Q2A1','Q2A2'], ['Q3A1','Q3A2','Q3A3','Q3A4']]})

tags = df3['Answers'].apply(pd.Series)
features = tags.rename(columns = lambda x : 'Answer_' + str(x))
result1= pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 0:3], features[:]], axis=1)
print (result1)
```

El resultado es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]